# populating spinner entries based on category selected

Tags: android, spinner

im trying to populate my spinner2 based on the category selected from previous spinner . i have different string arrays which would be used. i searched through the page to find something to help me but it all does not help 
here is my spinners

```
           spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
             frmCatg = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
            frmApplnce = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
            frmWatts = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
         inWatts = Integer.parseInt(frmWatts);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you select one item in the first spinner, you have to fill the list of your second spinner.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, <your string-array resource>;
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
```